# Chart drawing : Need to check anyChart Drawing is Completed

Tags: javascript, events, dom, charts, anychart

I am using anychart api latest version. I need some events for anychart

- check whether chart is added on DOM or not
- tigger other function after chart drawn completed, so I can get proper base64    of the chart

Need some function which tells about that chart is added on the DOM and created completely.

Answer (score 2):

You can use chartDraw event listed in https://api.anychart.com/latest/anychart.enums.EventType:

```
chart.listenOnce('chartDraw', function(){
    chart.getJpgBase64String(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

Here is a sample http://jsfiddle.net/wxw9pcqx/
with https://api.anychart.com/latest/anychart.core.Chart#getJpgBase64String function, it can be used with all other getXXXBase64String methods the same way.

Comment: Sorry, this not gone work. I need to find out that drawing of chart is completed or not on another button clicked

Comment: @kushal-jain this sample http://jsfiddle.net/wxw9pcqx/ has no buttons, it listens to chartDraw event and gets base64 when drawing is completed.

Comment: sorry you understand it wrong, I want that functionality on button click

Comment: and there is also this way, you've probably wanted it, sorry we couldn't understand that: http://jsfiddle.net/wxw9pcqx/3/

you can use isRendering() method of the chart stage, it is returned by container method.